# How to insert Null value to INT in mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

I have one field name is "owner". It is a foreign key Value. Initially i defined NULL value.

In PHP,

```
if($memberType=='owner'){
    $ownerId = "";
}else{
    $ownerId = $_POST['ownerId'];
}

$sql_user = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO user(firstname, lastname,owner_id) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$ownerId')");
```

Here Data is not inserting. When i remove owner_id during inserting, It is working.

How to define Null value to that

Comment: Simply send `NULL` as value

Comment: You must be sending it within quotation marks like `'NULL'`, it should be plain `NULL`

Comment: What error message are you getting? Suppressing error messages does not help you.

Comment: Thats right, Iam assign $ownerId= NULL. during inserting i not i not using the single quotation. Thats also not working for me.

Comment: The data is not inserting. I didn't get any error message

Comment: But you have single-quotation in arround `$ownerId` in your insert-Statement!

Comment: I removed that single quotation from insert statements. and that also not inserting

Answer (score 0):

Your sql is fine. edit column in mysql, remove NOT NULL in the column.

Comment: It is foreign key field. So i cant able to remove NULL

Comment: if its foreign key, why not just default it to 0 if value is null?

Comment: When i change from NULL to default 0. It shows data truncated error

Comment: this just means that you have a null value already in the column. its either you update all null to 0 then edit default value to 0 or continue with null insert

Comment: in php can you try using **null**

Comment: I tried so many possibilities but i cant resolve this one. I cant use null & NULL. If i use O it shown incorrect column id. If i use without single quaotation, it shows syntax error

Answer (score 0):

```
$ownerId=0;
if($memberType=='owner'){
    $ownerId = $_POST['ownerId'];
}

$sql_user = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO user(firstname, lastname,owner_id) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$ownerId')");
```